# Conditional Inserts SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table schema:

```
create table SerialNo2(
IncarnationID_UID counter primary key,
Mark integer
);
```

Now I want to add a new column in the table, let's call it `degree`. Given that I want to apply an update on production table, I will have to populate the `degree` column based on the `Mark` value for all the existing data in the `SerialNo2` table. The rule for this is that

```
if Mark>90 then degree='A',
else degree='B'
```

How to write a conditional SQL insert that will accomplish the above function?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your SQL DDL: remove the comma after the integer keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE SerialNo2 SET SerialNo2.Degree = IIf([Mark]>90,"A","B")
```

Answer (score 3):

Define the degree column as being nullable at first, then do an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE SerialNo2
SET Degree = CASE WHEN Mark > 90 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END
```

Comment: Tag indicates MS Access, which uses the syntax in @DJ's answer.

Comment: Yes, you've posted SQL-92 syntax, specifically the CASE statement, which ACE/Jet does not support.

Comment: ACE/Jet supports a form of SQL that is called SQL92 by Microsoft, but I don't know if it supports CASE.

Comment: MS calls it 'ANSI-92', "This mode conforms closely to the ANSI-92 Level 1 specification, but is not ANSI-92 Level 1 compliant" but the non-compliance is devastating for some basic syntax e.g. UPDATE.

Comment: ...and it does not support CASE, which should be easy to test e.g. SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Answer (score 0):

First create your new column (ANSI-92 Query Mode syntax):

```
ALTER TABLE SerialNo2 ADD 
   Degree CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'B' NOT NULL;
```

If you query the table immediately you will have `NULL` in the new column... which is a major bug in the engine IMO i.e. it should have set the value to the `DEFAULT` for each row however we now have a `NOT NULL` column that contains `NULL`s!!

So we have to `SET` the value for every row

```
UPDATE SerialNo2 
   SET Degree = IIF(Mark > 90, 'A', 'B');
```

BTW if you have more than one value to test, rather than nested `IIF`s, you could use the SWITCH keyword, using the TRUE valeu for the 'case else' clause e.g.

```
UPDATE SerialNo2 
   SET Degree = SWICTH(
                       Mark > 90, 'A', 
                       Mark <= 0, 'X', 
                       TRUE, 'B'
                      );
```